# Spring AMQP - Publisher confirms returns ack-ed when publish to non-existent queue

Tags: spring-boot, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

If I use publisher confirms and returns callback on RabbitMQ, I never get the returned message.
From Spring AMQP docs :

```
- Publish to an exchange but there is no matching destination queue.
- Publish to a non-existent exchange.
The first case is covered by publisher returns, as described in Publisher Confirms and Returns.
```

So I think I will get returned message if I publish to exist exchange, but not-exist queue. But the return callback never called. 
Do I need to set something else?
I'm using RabbitMQ 3.8.0 and Spring Boot 2.2.1

**application.yml**

```
spring:
  rabbitmq:
    publisher-confirms: true
    publisher-returns: true
    template:
      mandatory: true
```

**Producer**

```java
@Service
public class PublisherConfirmProducer {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PublisherConfirmProducer.class);

    @Autowired
    private RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate;

    @PostConstruct
    private void postConstruct() {
        this.rabbitTemplate.setConfirmCallback((correlation, ack, reason) -> {
            if (correlation != null) {
                log.info("Received " + (ack ? " ack " : " nack ") + "for correlation: " + correlation);
            }
        });

        this.rabbitTemplate.setReturnCallback((message, replyCode, replyText, exchange, routingKey) -> {
            log.info("Returned: " + message + "\nreplyCode: " + replyCode + "\nreplyText: " + replyText
                    + "\nexchange/rk: " + exchange + "/" + routingKey);
        });
    }

    // Careful : will be silently dropped, since the exchange is exists, but no
    // route to queue, but ack-ed. How to know that I publish to non-existing queue?
    public void sendMessage_ValidExchange_InvalidQueue(DummyMessage message) {
        CorrelationData correlationData = new CorrelationData("Correlation for message " + message.getContent());
        this.rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend("x.test", "not-valid-routing-key", message, correlationData);
    }

}
```

Main app

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class RabbitmqProducerTwoApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(RabbitmqProducerTwoApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Autowired
    private PublisherConfirmProducer producer;

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        var dummyMessage_2 = new DummyMessage("Message 2", 2);
        producer.sendMessage_ValidExchange_InvalidQueue(dummyMessage_2);
    }

}
```

**Log result**

```
2019-11-29 04:45:23.796  INFO 8352 --- [           main] c.c.r.RabbitmqProducerTwoApplication     : Starting RabbitmqProducerTwoApplication on timpamungkas with PID 8352 (D:\workspace\eclipse\my-courses\rabbitmq-1.2\rabbitmq-producer-two\bin\main started by USER in D:\workspace\eclipse\my-courses\rabbitmq-1.2\rabbitmq-producer-two)
2019-11-29 04:45:23.800  INFO 8352 --- [           main] c.c.r.RabbitmqProducerTwoApplication     : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2019-11-29 04:45:24.952  INFO 8352 --- [           main] c.c.r.RabbitmqProducerTwoApplication     : Started RabbitmqProducerTwoApplication in 1.696 seconds (JVM running for 3.539)
2019-11-29 04:45:24.990  INFO 8352 --- [           main] o.s.a.r.c.CachingConnectionFactory       : Attempting to connect to: [localhost:5672]
2019-11-29 04:45:25.024  INFO 8352 --- [           main] o.s.a.r.c.CachingConnectionFactory       : Created new connection: rabbitConnectionFactory#599f571f:0/SimpleConnection@86733 [delegate=amqp://guest@127.0.0.1:5672/, localPort= 50688]
2019-11-29 04:45:25.058  INFO 8352 --- [nectionFactory1] c.c.r.producer.PublisherConfirmProducer  : Received  ack for correlation: CorrelationData [id=Correlation for message Message 2]
```

---

Edited for Gary

RabbitMqConfig.java

```java
@Configuration
public class RabbitmqConfig {

    @Bean
    public Jackson2JsonMessageConverter converter() {
        return new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter();
    }

    @Bean
    public RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory, Jackson2JsonMessageConverter converter) {
        RabbitTemplate template = new RabbitTemplate(connectionFactory);
        template.setMessageConverter(converter);
        return template;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will receive a positive ack after a returned message.

What you have looks correct to me. It is very similar to [this sample](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-amqp-samples/tree/master/spring-rabbit-confirms-returns), so should work the same way.

What type of exchange is `x.test`? What queues are bound to it, and with what routing keys?

If you still can't get it to work after looking at that sample, post the project someplace and I'll take a look.

Comment: What type of exchange is `x.test`? What queues are bound to it, and with what routing keys?

Comment: Hi Gary. The "x.test" is direct exchange, bound to "q.test" with routing key "test". I can make it works after some try. I have a RabbitMQConfig.java that returns RabbitTemplate (see the code above). To make return callback works, I have to comment the Bean that returns RabbitTemplate on my config. Funny thing is, if I not comment the Bean, the confirm callback is triggered, but return callback is not triggered. Is this expected behaviour? By the way, I really admire what have you done for spring-amqp! It really helps me a lot! Thanks 3000 @gary-russell

Comment: I've put the code [here](https://github.com/timpamungkas/amqp-demo) if you don't mind to take a look. Thanks a lot

Comment: `spring.rabbitmq.template.*` properties are used by Boot when auto configuring a `RabbitTemplate`. Since you have your own bean, auto configuration is disabled, hence the `mandatory` property is not applied; you need to set the `mandatory` property yourself when you define your own template bean. Furthermore, Boot will detect your message converter and automatically wire it into the template, so you really don't need your own bean.

Answer (score 0):

Implementation looks correct, just implement your own Private callback class and extend ConfirmCallback to register the callback, set the ConfirmCallback when you initialize the RabbitTemplate.

```
 private static class PublisherCallback implements RabbitTemplate.ConfirmCallback {
    
    @Override
    public void confirm(CorrelationData correlationData, boolean ack, String cause) {
        System.out.println("Confirm message returned " + correlationData.toString() + " Ack " + ack + " cause " + cause);
    }

}

rabbitTemplate.setConfirmCallback(new PublisherCallback());
```

Answer (score 0):

I use Springboot 2.5.2, and RabbitMQ 3.8.18, when I bind my queue to a topic exchange  with an invalid routing key, my `ReturnsCallback` is called

```
@Bean(name = "binding")

Binding binding(@Qualifier("queue") Queue queue, @Qualifier("exchange") TopicExchange exchange) {

return BindingBuilder.bind(queue).to(exchange).with("aaa"+ Constants.VALID_ROUTING_KEY);
}

//configuration
rabbitTemplate.setConfirmCallback(confirmCallbackService);
rabbitTemplate.setReturnsCallback(returnCallbackService);
rabbitTemplate.setMandatory(true); //seems this config is mandatory


//logs
2021-07-08 15:08:05,078 ERROR [connectionFactory1] com..publisher.config.ReturnCallbackService: returnedMessage =>
```

[Rabbitmq-Batch-Rabbitmq-Publish-Subscribe](https://github.com/vikki-xiaohua/rabbitmq-batch-publish-subscribe)